# How do I make hyperlinks in a PDF open in AdobeReader rather than web browser?

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, pdfbox

I have implemented functionality to interlink a bunch of PDFs by adding hyperlinks in each PDF using PDFBox.
Here is the code:

```
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
Uri fileUri = new Uri(filePath);
action.setURI(fileUri.ToString());
txtLink.setAction(action);
```

But the problem is that when I click on a hyperlink in a PDF, it opens in a web browser rather in another instance of Adobe Acrobat reader.

So, how do I make the PDF open in the default program selected for PDFs rather that in the browser.

Edit: The hyperlinks path are like

> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Oliver%20Unlinked%20set%20-%20Copy/A8.1%20-%20INTERIOR%20ELEVATIONS.pdf

Comment: whats your file path look like, and what is your default application to open your pdf docs?

Comment: @Simon Price please see the edit.

Comment: Checkout Evermap Autobookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF paths must be in something they call device-independent form. See example below. Also, by including the protocol in your link (file://), you are actually telling Acrobat to open it in a browser.

```
/c/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat DC/Help/AcroHelp.pdf
```

Comment: But this path contains information of drive and folders, how do we specify path which is relative to the path of the file in which the hyperlink resides.

Comment: You use the same format, just with a relative path. Notice you don't need to escape the string though.